# Rapid change in UI -- what do I miss about jQuery width?

Tags: jquery

I use such code to get the width of the document:

```
$(document).width()
```

But I noticed that my layout is constantly broken when resizing the window, I did some tests and I found out that the speed of the change is crucial. When I resize the window very slowly, the value of the width is correct. But when I resize the window rapidly (in one move by 50%), the width read is from previous state.

For comparison I added

```
document.body.getBoundingClientRect()
```

The second approach gives me reliable reading all the time, no matter how rapid is the change of the window.

OK, I found what should I use, but I would like to know what is wrong with jQuery approach. So what do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, jQuery wraps the original javascript. 
You realized that $ is made up in jQuery? 
That is why, I think it makes sense that jQuery performs slower than the original javascript code.
There may be something they did first in .width() function before the results get to you. 
Try [this](http://jsperf.com/jq-width-vs-client-width) link for your reference

Thank you,